# How can use ActionCable broadcast_to with specific group of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have a basic setup with rails API + devise_token_auth + actionable and angular9 app for the Front.

I basically want to send notifications to a specific group of users not all users.

My code looks like follows:

***connections.rb***

```
module ApplicationCable
 class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  identified_by :current_user

def connect
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
end

private
def find_verified_user
  uid = request.query_parameters[:uid]
  token = request.query_parameters[:token]
  client_id = request.query_parameters[:client]

  user = User.find_by_uid(uid)

  if user && user.valid_token?(token, client_id)
    user
  else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
  end
end
end
end
```

***appointments.rb***

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
validates_uniqueness_of :start_time
belongs_to :slug
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :property
belongs_to :contact


after_create do
  ChangeAppointmentsJob.perform_later self
end

after_update do
  ChangeAppointmentsJob.perform_later self
end
end
```

***ChangeAppointmentsJob***

```
class ChangeAppointmentsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(appointment)

    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'appointment_channel', data: appointment
  end

end
```

***AppointmentChannel***

```
class AppointmentChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'appointment_channel'
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

I want to do something like this

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast_to( User.where(slug_id: current_user.slug_id) )
```

to send a notification to my Front app but ***not to all users***, just users who had *slug_id* like the user who created or updated the appointment

any ideas, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

I send slug_id with the uid, access_token and client for subscribing to the channel and I use it in connection.rb like this

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  identified_by :current_user

def connect
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
end

private
def find_verified_user
  uid = request.query_parameters[:uid]
  token = request.query_parameters[:token]
  client_id = request.query_parameters[:client]
  slug_id = request.query_parameters[:slug_id]
  user = User.where(slug_id: slug_id).find_by_uid(uid)  <-------- get all users with the same slug_id :)

  if user && user.valid_token?(token, client_id)
    user
  else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
  end
 end
end
end
```